# remove multiple headers after importing csv files in excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I need to combine hundreds of csv files with the same format to one without having duplicate headers using an excel makro.
I can select the files I want to import (and import them) with the following code:

```
Dim dateien, i, lastrow
lastrow = 1
dateien = Application.GetOpenFilename _
("csv-Dateien (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(dateien) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(dateien)
        Workbooks.Open dateien(i), local:=True
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & lastrow)
            lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next i
End If
```

However i don't really have a clue how to remove the duplicate headers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take the approach of opening each file in a `FileSystemObject`, reading all its data in and then firing it back out without the headers myself:

```
Dim dateien, i, lastrow
lastrow = 1
dateien = Application.GetOpenFilename _
("csv-Dateien (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)

dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oSourceFile, oTargetFile
Set oTargetFile = oFso.CreateTextFile("pathtofilehere", True)
Dim sArray()

If IsArray(dateien) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(dateien) ' Arrays in VBA index from zero, not 1 - you're skipping the first element in dateien
        ReDim sArray(0)
        Set oSourceFile = oFso.OpenTextFile(dateien(i), 1) ' open for reading
        While Not oSourceFile.AtEndOfStream ' while there is data in the file
            sArray(Ubound(sArray)) = oSourceFile.ReadLine  ' add the line to an array
            ReDim Preserve sArray(UBound(sArray)+1) ' increase size of the array by 1
        Wend
        ' Now we have the whole file in an array
        For myLoop = 1 to UBound(sArray) ' Loop from 1 and we skip the header line in the file
            oTargetFile.WriteLine sArray(myLoop) ' write array values into file
        Next myLoop   ' repeat for each line in the array
    Next i    ' repeat for each file in dateien
End If
```

Comment: Seems to be a good idea, however I get a compilation error at `ReDim Preserve sArray(UBound(sArray))` (**Array Already Dimensioned**); If I declare `sArray ()`, I get the runtime error **Subscript out of range (Error 9)** at `sArray(UBound(sArray)) = oSourceFile.ReadLine`

Comment: Oops.  Fixed in code now...  The trick is to declare it as dynamic initially with `Dim sArray()` then redimension it so it has the expected upper boundary for the first element with a `ReDim`

Comment: I still get **Error 9 (Subscript out of range)** for `Set oSourceFile = oFso.OpenTextFile(dateien(i), 1)` :(

Comment: Having checked with the code directly, it seems that the array returned by `Application.GetOpenFileName` is not zero indexed, rather indexed from 1. I've modified the answer; should work now.  Let me know if there's any issues

Comment: It's compiling and working without error now, however it doesn't get rid of all the headers, only the first (wich i want to keep anyways), second, fourth, seventh, eleventh, sixteenth and so on.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of headers in each file?  The code is only excluding the first line of the file as output, so if there are multiple headers within a single file, the remaining headers would be left in place.  If you can confirm one way or the other, there's a simple enough solution to it

Comment: No, every file only has one row of headers.

Comment: I've moved the `ReDim sArray(0)` statement so that it resets for each file; previously it was always appending the other file's data to the original array.  This will clear it out for each file and should properly resolve your header issue